# I have to work with Microsoft Office Document imaging withMS office 2010 through .Net. How do I do it?

Tags: .net, ms-office, modi

I have MS Office 2010 in my system and I need to install Microsoft Office document Imaging (MODI). As it is not available in 2010 , i have followed the steps(method 3) given in

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760

site and have installed MODI.But I cannot see the MODI in my start menu, but can check it through command prompt

I have downloaded the  MDIVWCTL.DLL and am trying to register it, but i am not able to as it says the specified module could not be found.

Now I want to know how to use this through .NET. Pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to your .net project. When adding a reference, go to the com tab and look for Ms Office Document Imaging Library (MODI) 12.0.